# SVG foreignObject doesn,t transform in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, compatibility

I am using d3.js to visualize a graph with nodes and edges. I used foreignObject tag for implementing custom labels for nodes. This is my code for adding foreinObjects to the nodes.

```
node.append("svg:g").attr("x",12).attr("y",".31em").attr("pointer-events","none").append("svg:foreignObject")
.attr("width",400).attr("height",400).append("xhtml:body").style("background-color","transparent").append("xhtml:div").attr("class","node_lables_html").html(function(d,i){
    return node_labels_html[parseInt(d.num)];
});
```

This is how it looks in the html. This is a html code for one node:

```
<g transform="translate(130.53028822246984,182.7303426183812)">
    <circle style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);" r="7" class="node node8"></circle>
         <g pointer-events="none" y=".31em" x="12">
               <foreignObject height="400" width="400">
                     <body style="background-color: transparent;">
                           <div style="display: inline-block;" class="node_lables_html">
                                 <table style="font-size: 18px">
                                      <tbody><tr>
                                              <td>
                                                     port
                                               </td>
                                       </tr>
                                  </tbody></table>
 </div></body></foreignObject></g></g>
```

I also have zooming and panning feature enabled in my SVG. There is `<g>` tag which contain all the nodes and edges and transform them accordingly. Everything works perfectly in Firefox. But when I tried it in Google Chrome the labels are just showing and not moving with the nodes. Does Chrome support transforming foreignObjects?